# Split string of possibly adjacent elements of unknown length by type in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string, loops

Given a string (actually a svg path) such as:

```
"M72 0v754h405v-86h-311v-211h302v-86h-302v-285h311v-86h-405z"
```

I want to obtain an array where each element is either a letter, either a full positive or negative number, like this:

```
[M, 72, 0, v, 754, h, 405, v, -86, h, -311, v, -211, h, 302, v, -86, h, -302, v, -285, h, 311, v, -86, h, -405, z]
```

I thought about using `split()` with a regex, but I believe that would not work with adjacent elements such as `"M72"` as there is nothing between them that I can target for the split.

Is the only solution a custom char per char loop that finds the beginning and end of each type of element I am looking for, possibly with regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match either a letter or a number with an optional minus sign.

```js
var string = "M72 0v754h405v-86h-311v-211h302v-86h-302v-285h311v-86h-405zx-12.4y0.001",
    parts = string.match(/[a-z]|-?\d+\.?\d*/gi);
    
console.log(parts);
```

Comment: I believe this breaks with decimal numbers, as in -86.5 , in the sense that -86 and 5 get separated. How can be fixed in the regex? thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could use SVG.js to achieve this: https://svgjs.dev/docs/2.7/classes/#svg-patharray

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track with regex, but you can take advantage of the fact that with `split`, any capturing groups in the pattern will be returned along with the strings on either side of the match.

A pattern like `/\s*([-+]?\d+)\s*/g` will select any numbers *and* split the string around those numbers. The result may contain empty strings, but those can be removed with `filter` pretty easily.

```js
var input = "M72 0v754h405v-86h-311v-211h302v-86h-302v-285h311v-86h-405z";
var result = input.split(/\s*([-+]?\d+)\s*/g).filter(String);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This answer works, but Nina Scholz's answer is more succint imo. No need for .filter()

Comment: No problem. I'm glad you were able to find a solution. FWIW, Piort Szlagura's solution is actually more *correct* if you only want to parse valid SVG Paths.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @p-s-w-g , I'll be doing this in node.js most possibly, so I wanted to avoid libraries, particularly something complex as svg.js but I see your point